# Rails migration not recognizing new column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I am trying to fun a migration to shift some data around.  In the previous migration I run the following:

```
add_column :portfolios, :owner_id, :integer
```

Then in the following migration is as follows:
    class MoveUserIdToPortfolio < ActiveRecord::Migration

```
  class Stake < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

  class UserStakeInPortfolio < Stake
    belongs_to :portfolio, foreign_key: :possession_id

    def self.sti_name
      'UserStakeInPortfolio'
    end
  end

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_stake_in_portfolios, foreign_key: :owner_id
    has_many :portfolios, through: :user_stake_in_portfolios
    has_many :personal_portfolios, through: :user_stake_in_portfolios, :class_name => 'PersonalPortfolio', :source => :portfolio, :conditions => { :type => 'PersonalPortfolio' }

    def personal_portfolio
      self.personal_portfolios.first
    end
  end

  class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

  class PersonalPortfolio < Portfolio

    def self.sti_name
      'PersonalPortfolio'
    end
  end

  def up

    puts "DEBUG: #{Portfolio.inspect}"

    Portfolio.connection.schema_cache.clear!
    Portfolio.reset_column_information
    PersonalPortfolio.connection.schema_cache.clear!
    PersonalPortfolio.reset_column_information
    User.connection.schema_cache.clear!
    User.reset_column_information

    puts "DEBUG2: #{Portfolio.inspect}"

    User.all.each do |user|
      pp = user.personal_portfolio
      puts "DEBUG3: #{pp.inspect}"
      pp.owner_id = user.id
      pp.save
      puts "DEBUG4: #{pp.inspect}"
    end

  end

  def down

  end
end
```

The strange thing here is that the pp.owner_id is never set.  And the output (that follows) never shows it attempting to update the owner_id, although it doesn't error out.

```
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
(0.3ms)  UPDATE `portfolios` SET `updated_at` = '2013-09-11 22:16:06' WHERE `portfolios`.`type` IN ('PersonalPortfolio') AND `portfolios`.`id` = 4
(0.4ms)  COMMIT
```

The `DEBUG` statement shows a `Portfolio` without an `owner_id` attribute.  But the `DEBUG2` outputs it with one.  But the the two `pp.inspect` outputs both do not show an instance with `owner_id`.

Happy to provide more information if it's helpful!

Comment: Can you change save to save!, so we can see the exception that is getting raised (if any).

Comment: Also, I almost always prefer to use update_all in a migration so that the migration can remain as independent from the model code as possible.  Using active record in a migration can cause you to run into scenarios where you can't run the migration without having the correct version of the model code in place at the same time.

Comment: It doesn't product any error when using `save!`.  Same thing happens.  Also, not sure how to use update_all in this situation as the value is different for each portfolio.